# How do I animate a graph

Tags: java, swing

So I've made a simple sine wave in Java. I just wanted to know how I could possibly go about "animating" the wave to show a waveform movement.

[image: Sine wave]

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class WavePane extends JPanel
{
    int width = Waves.WIDTH, height = Waves.HEIGHT;
    final int SPEED = 4; // 1000ms

    Timer timer;
    int phase;

    public WavePane() {
        phase = 0;
        timer = new Timer(SPEED, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                phase++;
                repaint();

                if(phase >= 360) {
                    phase = 0;
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);

        drawWave(g, width, height, phase);
    }

    private void drawWave(Graphics g, int width, int height, int phase) {
        for(double x = -(width / 2); x <= (width / 2); x = x + 0.5) {
            double y = 50 * Math.sin((x + phase) * (Math.PI / 180));

            int x1 = (int)x;
            int y1 = (int)y;

            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            g.drawLine((width / 2) + x1, (height / 2) - y1 - 1, (width / 2) + x1, (height / 2) - y1 - 1);
            g.drawLine((width / 2) + x1, (height / 2) - y1, (width / 2) + x1, (height / 2) - y1);
            g.drawLine((width / 2) + x1, (height / 2) - y1 + 1, (width / 2) + x1, (height / 2) - y1 + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works and animation works too! But how can i make it **smoother**??

Comment: Usually all animations are implemented using `javax.swing.Timer`. But what animation you need?

Comment: Yes, use a Swing `Timer` as suggested by @SergiyMedvynskyy, then change `private void drawWave(Graphics g, int width, int height) {` to something like `private void drawWave(Graphics g, int width, int height, double phase) {` & add the `phase` to `x` in the `Math.sin(x * (Math.PI / 180));` expression when drawing.

Comment: Okay I updated the OP with my new code. The animation works, but how can I make it smoother (no stutter when it reaches 360?)

Comment: *"no stutter when it reaches 360?"* 1) You realize that the math functions work with radians as opposed to degrees, right? 2) I did an animation here and just kept adding to the `phase` (declared as a `double`). There should be no problem till [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE) ..

Comment: Tip: Add @SergiyMedvynskyy (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `repaint()` method had to be called every update tick, to update whatever is to be rendered on the screen.